# multi-condition sampling returns a blank

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get a list of messages that are less than `message.create_date`. When user asks for chat history he gets list of 50 messages and to get next 50 he sends date of last message creation and I have to search all next messages which `message.create_date` is less than filter which user sends.

```js
db.message.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            chat_id: "5XboYfS02SCb1D_4RiDB"
          },
          {
            $lte: [
              "create_date",
              1675174095184 // filter
            ],
            
          },
          
        ]
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 50,
    
  },
  {
    $project: {
      id: 1,
      chat_id: 1,
      from_id: 1,
      create_date: 1,
      type: 1,
      media: 1,
      body: 1,
      update_at: 1,
      modifications: 1,
    }
  },
  
])
```

Here is how I tried to solve this problem:

[My solution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kJ4bsxm8XNo)

But unfortunately I get a blank response, I attached an example and you can see that because I use:

```
$lte: [
   "create_date", 
   1675174095184
]
```

I get a blank response.

How do I filter the data to find messages by chat ID and the condition that `message.create_date` is less than the number I get from the client

```
$lte: [
   "create_date", 
   1675174095184(this is the value that acts as the filter, it comes from the client)
]
```

Comment: try with `$lte: [
   "$create_date", 
   1675174095184
]`. Note the dollar sign

Comment: @ray, i try, but it doesn't work, I get a blank

Comment: the syntax should be correct. Just the timestamp 1675174095184 is too small to match any document. Try with different timestamp like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YFXqlrd67o4)

Comment: @ray, I added more data, and as you can see, I'm not getting quite what I should. Can you tell me why `match chat_id: "b199ceba-78bb-4204-859e-5a1be228b2b5"` is not working, or rather I get two correct objects and two from another chat. Why is this happening and how can I get rid of it?
Also, when you test, change $sort {create_date: -1}, to 1 and then you will get a significantly different response. It will search ALL CHATS, how can I fix this? [New example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/frO9sEzPpUB)

Comment: What is *not working*? If you view in the playgound with selecting `$match` stage in the dropdown, you can see it picks up the records it should pick up. Those being left out either having different chat_id or not having create_date/create_date is greater than your threshold